# Why did Charles Lamb not preserve the real name of his lover?

Tags: essays, charles-lamb

In the 12th paragraph of “Dream Children: A Reverie,” written when Charles Lamb was 44 years old, we find:

> Then I told how for seven long years, in hope sometimes, sometimes in despair, yet persisting ever, I courted the fair Alice W—-n

Why didn't Lamb write the original name? And was the name Alice W—-n inspired by something else?